# How to lock a row over a SELECT followed by an UPDATE

Tags: oracle, locking

What is the best way to lock an individual row in the following scenario:

```
--TODO - LOCK THIS ROW
-- Return the next id
SELECT  next_id
INTO    next_id_out
FROM owner.my_id_table
WHERE   app_id = app_id_in;

-- Update the next id on the table
UPDATE owner.my_id_table
SET next_id = next_id_out + 1
WHERE app_id = app_id_in;
```

I need to make sure that nothing changes the id table between me
selecting the id and updating the table with the next available id.

PS. yes I am new to oracle :)

Comment: If you are doing that in PL/SQL or another programming language, you can use `update ... returning ...`. No need for the `select`  and you'll get then new value back as a result of the `update` statement directly. But this is not usable from "plain" SQL, only within a programming language

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add a `FOR UPDATE` to your `SELECT`

```
SELECT  next_id
INTO    next_id_out
FROM owner.my_id_table
WHERE   app_id = app_id_in
FOR UPDATE;
```

Of course, it doesn't make much sense to use a `SELECT` to lock a row immediately before updating it.  Just running the `UPDATE` will lock the row.

Comment: My requirement is.... a user should update a next_id with increment of 1 and fetch that updated value and do he's work.                            UPDATE owner.my_id_table
SET next_id = next_id_out + 1
WHERE app_id = app_id_in;                                                                    -------------------------------------------------                                                           SELECT  next_id
FROM owner.my_id_table
WHERE   app_id = app_id_in;                                                              SO when executing these statement another user should not interfere,

Comment: @iprashant7: you can use `update ... returning` to get the result without any `select` statement. But you need to do this from within a programming language (PL/SQL, Java, ...) it's not possible in "plain" SQL